# Microsoft account and IdentityServer4

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

I have setup an external auth with IdentityServer4 but I can't seem to figure out how to read Microsoft profile when user is authenticated.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using Azure AD?  If so, and you are being correctly redirected to the Microsoft login page to enter your credentials, I would suggest looking [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/samples/Quickstarts/4_ImplicitFlowAuthenticationWithExternal/src/IdentityServer/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs) in the IdentityServer4 samples (specifically the ExternalLoginCallback function).

That will call a couple other functions you can use to translate the information you received back from Microsoft into IdentityServer claims that you can use.

Comment: To save others the trouble I had, the link in the above answwer does not work, it is now: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/master/Quickstarts/4_ImplicitFlowAuthenticationWithExternal/src/IdentityServer/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs

Comment: It apparently was broken again, so I updated my answer.